# How to specify @microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior in the request body in onedriveAPI

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm working on a C# project with these requirements:

1. Create a Folder if it doesn't exits
2. Check if the already exists, if it exists increment the file name.

From Onedrive API documentation [Create a new Folder in OneDrive](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/create.htm/), it says that setting @microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior=rename would increment the folder value if it exists

how can I add the @microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior into my request?

Here's the code which creates the folder using drive Item

```
var foldertoCreate = new DriveItem {
    Name = $"TestFolder",
    Folder = new Folder (),

};

var newFolder = await _graphClient.Drive
    .Items["MyParent_Item_Id"]
    .Children
    .Request ()
    .AddAsync (foldertoCreate);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you should be able to add the annotation manually via `AdditionalData`. Obviously this isn't ideal, but I cannot see another way to do it with the current SDK.

```
var foldertoCreate = new DriveItem
{
    Name = $"TestFolder",
    Folder = new Folder(),
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "rename" }
    },
};

var newFolder = await _graphClient.Drive
    .Items["MyParent_Item_Id"]
    .Children
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(foldertoCreate);
```

Comment: what to do if we dont want to replace or rename just dont create folder

Comment: You can specify "fail" for the `conflictBehavior` and it'll fail with a `409 Conflict`

Comment: Even in the Official documentation from Microsoft they use @microsoft as a existing property. What a miss...