# How to specify @microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior directly into OneDrive SDK call

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45910274/how-to-specify-microsoft-graph-conflictbehavior-in-the-request-body-in-onedrive/) following on from my previous question,

Is there a way where,can we add the `@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior` annotation directly into the SDK call rather than specifying it in the `foldertoCreate` object?

```
var foldertoCreate = new DriveItem {
    Name = $"TestFolder",
    Folder = new Folder (),
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object> { 
        { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "rename" }
    },
};

// somewhere in the below call

var newFolder = await _graphClient.Drive
    .Items["MyParent_Item_Id"]
    .Children
    .Request ()
    .AddAsync (foldertoCreate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just you looking to consolidate your code, you could create afolder call using single call:

```
var newFolder = await _graphClient.Drive.Items["MyParent_Item_Id"].Children.Request ().AddAsync (new DriveItem () {
    Name = $"TestFolder",
    Folder = new Folder (),
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "rename" } }
});
```